# After installing bootstrap my local css modules are no longer loading in webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, vue.js, module

I'm new to webpack and vue.js both, and was doing pretty well using the vue webpack template... up until I attempted to install and require bootstrap in addition to my own styles.css file.

Initially, I added

```
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use:['style-loader','css-loader']
      },
```

to my webpack.base.config file, and then created a /styles subfolder in my /src folder to hold my styles.css file. Added import './styles/styles.css' to my main.js file, saved, and voila! It was working.

I needed to add bootstrap, so I used `npm install bootstrap` and `npm install jquery popper.js`. Then I added `require ('bootstrap'`) to my main.js... and suddenly, I was getting the error

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./style/mainstyle.css in ./src/main.js
```

Even after removing the bootstrap `require`, it's still throwing the same error. I even tried deleting and recreating my /styles/styles.css folder structure... nada.

After searches online provided little assistance, I decided to go ahead and uninstall bootstrap, jquery, and popper.js. Unfortunately, that still has not helped.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is that's going wrong, or how to fix it. Should I scrap it and start over?

Edit: I have restarted my dev server since the problem happened, just in case that was the issue.

Update: tried changing the relative path, but got the same errors. Changed it back... and now I'm getting this:

```
 WAIT  Compiling...                                                     11:39:41

 94% asset optimization                                                       i    
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                 11:39:41

This relative module was not found:

* ./mainstyle.css in ./src/main.js


 WAIT  Compiling...                                                     11:39:51

 94% asset optimization                                                       l    
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                 11:39:51

 error  in ./src/styles/mainstyle.css

Module build failed: Unknown word (5:1)

  3 | // load the styles
  4 | var content = require("!!../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--7-1!../../node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??ref--7-2!./mainstyle.css");
> 5 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
    | ^
  6 | if(content.locals) module.exports = content.locals;
  7 | // add the styles to the DOM
  8 | var update = require("!../../node_modules/vue-style-loader/lib/addStylesClient.js")("62b80dbc", content, false, {});


 @ ./src/styles/mainstyle.css 2:14-232 21:1-42:3 22:19-237
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

I will freely admit that I don't really understand what it's telling me, but I do know that I haven't changed that file.

Comment: Maybe your Webpack configuration doesn't allow you to use both `import` and `require()`. Can you replace the `require('bootstrap')` with the `import 'bootstrap'` syntax?

Comment: I did so, and currently it seems to be all but ignoring bootstrap, but the build refuses to compile. The breaking issue is one that appeared out of nowhere-- "module build failed: Unknown word" -- it's pointing to an "if" in the postcss-loader index.js file, which obviously I've never touched.